# Compiling a wxWidgets application with MinGW from prompt under Windows XP

Tags: compilation, cmd, mingw, wxwidgets

Well, that's it. I'm sure the title is descriptive enough.
I'm trying to compile a hello world sort of application I wrote in C++ with wxWidgets.
I have four files, let's call them frame1.h, frame1.cpp, main.h and main.cpp.

I just need a simple (if possible) method to compile the application from the cmd prompt,
preferably from a .bat script file.

I googled it, but everything I found was about compiling the wxWidgets library, which I already did, or compiling applications with Visual Studio or other IDEs like Code::Blocks. I just want to do it from the command prompt with MinGW. I found a method that used back ticks but those aren't supported in Windows and I don't even know if it would work even if there was a workaround of some sort.

I know asking for a step by step method would be too pretentious but it would be very appreciated. Of course, I know that might not be possible, but I doubt compiling an application can be rocket science and probably I'm just missing something very obvious cause I'm stupid.

EDIT: I compile my applications like this...

```
g++ -Wall -c -o ClassFile.o ClassFile.cpp
g++ -Wall -o Program.exe ClassFile.o main.cpp
```

...for example. I'm looking for a similar method to compile wxWidget apps.

Well, thank you.
Good luck.

Comment: `compiling the wxWidgets library, which I already did`. Have you then a directory  `\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_dll` and `\wxWidgets\lib\gcc_lib` ?

Comment: There is a gcc_dll directory, but no gcc_lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already compiled wxWidgets successfully, go to the `samples/minimal` subdirectory and type `make -f makefile.gcc -n`. This will show you the commands used to build the minimal sample, including all wxWidgets-specific options you must use for both the compilation and link commands. Unfortunately, if you use cmd.exe your only solution is to manually copy-paste these options in another window (replacing "minimal" with your program name, of course) as, as you already know, it doesn't support the command substitution (backticks) mechanism.

As this gets tiresome pretty quickly, the usual thing to do is to write a makefile, even if it's just a very simple one, where these options are defined in variables that are then reused for all files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I'm now learning about makefiles. Guess I 'd have to sooner or later anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a video on this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6FDNR3lh8E
Here is small and simple steps to follow.

Pre-Requirements :

1. GNU g++ compiler downloaded and installed.
2. Set gcc/g++ path to Enviroment Variable.
3. Download WxWidgets Binaries : 1. Header Files, 2. Development Files, 3. DLLs.
4. Extract then one folder as it is. I have extracted them at D:\WxAPI Folder.
   Looks Like :
   D:
   - WxAPI Folder
   - include (Header files has this folder ziped in .7z)
   - lib (Development Files & DLL has this folder ziped in .7z and both extracts in this save folder)
5. Set your project development structure.

   My Project Development Structure :

   ```
    WxExample (Project Folder)
        - Build (Folder) : Contains debug and release dlls and exe
            - debug (Folder) : Contains debug specific dlls and exe.
            - release (Folder) : Contains release specific dlls and exe.
        - inlcude (Folder) : Contains project header files.
        - src (Folder) : Contains project .cpp files.
        - wxCompiler.cmd : Contains compile command created with following steps.
   ```

- Write Compilation Command

  - Link Following to Compile.

  1. First Compile Project *.cpp Files :
     g++ ".\src*.cpp"
  2. Give Project Output .exe Name :
     -o ".\build\release\Project_Name.exe"
  3. Show Project .h File Location to g++ :
     -I ".\include"
  4. Provide WxWidget .h Files :
     -I "D:\WxAPI\include"
  5. Locate WxWidget setup.h File :
     -I "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu"
  6. Supply Binaries Location of WxWidgets :
     -L "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll"
  7. Provide Compile Flags :
     -l wxbase31u
     -l wxmsw31u_core

  - Here D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\libwxbase31u.a File Renamed To "wxbase31u"
    & D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\libwxmsw31u_core.a File Renamed To "wxmsw31u_core" as flag.
  - You have to add similar file flag as you used in your project as .h
  - For Example :
    -lwxmsw31u_core  -lwxbase31u    -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng   -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet -loleacc -luxtheme
  - Here is Full Command :
    g++ ".\src*.cpp" -o ".\build\release" -I "D:\WxExample\include" -I "D:\WxAPI\include" -I "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll\mswu" -L "D:\WxAPI\lib\gcc810_x64_dll" -l wxbase31u -l wxmsw31u_core
  - Run wxWidgets.cmd and that's it. Your exe is in your .\Build\release folder.

  8. Set WxWidget DLL path in Enviroment Variable.
     If you do not want to copy paste required dll to your release/debug folder.