# wxWidgets Dynamically linked library error

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've been looking to build wxWidgets app with MinGW:
[Compiling a wxWidgets application with MinGW from prompt under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713244/compiling-a-wxwidgets-application-with-mingw-from-prompt-under-windows-xp)

After successfully building the executables with demo code in wxWidgets document, I put them together with the directory where the DDL release files I downloaded on their site.

But after running that executable file, the following error is displayed:

> main.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point *ZNSt15basic_streambuflcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekposESt4fpo sliESt13_los_Openmode could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\CODE\C++\wxWidgets\TEST\src\wxmsw32u_core_gcc1210* x64.dll.

[image: Image of the above error]

My MinGW contains gcc and g++ version 12.1.0, wxWidgets library I download Windows Binaries MSYS2 MinGW-w64 12.1

I successfully compile with the command:

> g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -l wxbase32u -l wxmsw32u_core

Comment: [Edit] your question and post all errors as text.  You probably want to provide a [mcve] (directly in the question) too.

Comment: If you have installed the correct runtime dlls for your compiler you probably need an older compiler for it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by `After successfully building the executables with demo code in wxWidgets document, I put them together with the directory where the DDL release files I downloaded on their site.`? Did you want to say - you copied that directory to another machine?

Comment: @MinhCoHuynh, also download the debug version of the library and build the Debug version of your executable. And make sure the proper libraries are downloaded.. (meaning for the compiler you are using)

Comment: Finally are you really looking to build something for more than decade years old OS, such as XP? In this case you probably will have to build wxWidgets and your application yourself by using the older compiler that is XP compatible...